# Error resolving class with excel-report plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am trying to install excel-plugin but I got an error resolving class.

```
..\plugins\excel-export-0.2.1\src\groovy\pl\touk\excel\export\XlsxExporter.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class groovy.transform.TypeChecked
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import groovy.transform.TypeChecked
   ^
```

as installations say I have this in my BuildConfig file.
    inherits("global") {

```
    excludes 'xercesImpl'
    excludes 'xercesImpl', 'xml-apis'

   }

    plugins {
        runtime (":excel-export:0.2.1")
   }
```

Any ideas ? I dont know which library I need.
I am using Grails 2.1.5

Comment: the interface is from groovy itself.  groovy 2.0 (iirc!) introduces it and would asume, that grails 2.1.5 is using it.  so this is odd.

Comment: i can see this issue on grails 2.1.1 too. I presume this is because grails 2.1.1 ships with groovy 1.8.8

Comment: i can also see this issue on Grails 2.1.5 (albeit quite old now). Please see the raised bug at [excel-export GitHub](https://github.com/TouK/excel-export/issues/42)

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem. 
If you just uncomment the annotation at the start of the AdditionalSheet.groovy and XlsxExporter.groovy (and the import), your project should compile.

Comment: and the next time the plugin gets pulled in again (e.g. after a proper clean) the error is there again.

Comment: since the class should be avaiable in grails 2 but apparently isnt, i wrote this solution.